# remove the “page name” field from the EnterpriseWiki.aspx page layout

Tags: 2013, development, page-layout, publishing-site, wiki-pages

I am working on an Enterprise wiki site collection inside SP 2013, currently when a user wants to create a new wiki page he will go through the following steps:-

1. Enter the wiki page name, as follow:-

[image]

2. Then he will be redirected to another page to enter the page content and edit the page name.

But I am facing some problems if the user edit the wiki page name after the redirect, where some users will get “unexpected exception”, so I am planning to remove the Page name field from the Enterprisewiki.aspx page layout, where I will remove the following code:-

```
<b class="ewiki-pagename-align">

<SharePoint:FieldLabel FieldName="FileLeafRef" runat="server"/>

</b>
<SharePoint:FileField id="PageNameInEditMode" CssClass="ewiki-pagename-align" FieldName="FileLeafRef" DisableInputFieldLabel="true" runat="server"/><br/>
```

And if the user wants to change the page name, he can edit the page properties as follow:-

[image]

So my question is if removing the Wiki page name field from the EnterPriseWiki.aspx page layout is valid approach that I can follow ? or it might cause some problems I am unaware of ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is no problem using your suggested approach. That can be useful when you are working on some static kind of stuffs. I usually prefer this kind of approach, when static content is there.

> Thing you need to remember is that in case you are upgrading your SharePoint with cumulative update, there might be a chance that that wiki page will get updated, so you need to do the same thing again to apply that effect (Depends on Microsoft whether they update the page or not).

Hope this helps!